# Sinch (javascript SDK) instant messaging history

Tags: javascript, chat, sinch

I have set up the Instant message example of the Sinch javascript SDK and everything works perfect. I've noticed that it is possible to chat with users that aren't online. But when you log in with that user, then he doesn't receive the messages that were send to him.

In the iOS & Android documentation of Sinch Instant messaging I found this information about history:

> Note: Messages are stored in the backend for 30 days before being
>   removed. If the recipient has not started the app and downloaded the
>   message history within this time, the message will be lost and no
>   notification received.

Is it possible to fetch messages history with Sinch javascript SDK? Because I can't find anything about it in that documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, no the javascript is not getting history

Comment: And will this be implemented in the future? So at the moment the best way for having history is to store all the outgoing messages in a database and show them to the user on login?